# Merge tar files in Windows Server

Tags: windows, merge, filesystems, gzip, tar

In my server(windows server) I have 3 tar files. (file.tar,  file.tar-2, file.tar-3). I want to merge those files. (Those are generated by some server tool).

So I am looking for a tool to merge those files. I tried winrar, 7zip. But no help.
The total size of those files are around 400mb.

Please help me to merge those files.

Thank You

Comment: This is something for superuser or serverfault. Try `tar` for windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a hold of a GNU tar executable (you could use Cygwin or MinGW) then you can use the `-A` option. Take a look at [this page](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/tar/tar_54.html) for examples of the uage.